# Data from ESP32 to AWS S3

Tags: aws, esp32

Can someone here help me out with code to send data from esp32 to aws s3 storage ?

I am using esp-idf as I have other code running on the esp32 as well.

I am new to aws so any help would be good.

Comment: Are you also using AWS IoT, which has integrations with S3, or do you just want to send data directly to S3?

Comment: ESP32 would be collecting sensor data and this data should be sent directly to S3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the complete answer but a step forward: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/getting_started_espressif.html

AWS has released their ESP32 support with AWS FreeRTOS.

To send directly to S3 without going through IoT Core, you will need your endpoint (obviously) and certificates on the device side to authenticate on the Cloud side. With the policies and Roles on the Cloud side, a trusted device should be able to post on S3.

Comment: Do you know which functions to use to send data as the test demo shows on MQTT transfer but my data is probably in KBs which MQTT can't handle

Comment: @HiteshPratyushV The [MQTT spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718023) allows for message payloads up to 256 **MB**; data on the order of a few kilobytes should pose no problem.

Comment: @HiteshPratyushV  did this well upvoted answer help you? If so, please click the tick mark to accept it, which will help others who read this question in future

Comment: @HiteshPratyushV were you able to upload data to the S3 bucket if yes were you uploading files can you please share the pointers if you were uploading files to the S3 bucket as I am trying the same